# Nginx download "*.php" instead of display it contents in a Docker environment

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, docker

I am working in a new Docker environment running [PHP71 + Nginx](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker). The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/Dockerfile) is inherit from [million12/docker-nginx](https://github.com/million12/docker-nginx).

This is the content of `/etc/nginx/hosts.d/vhost.conf` (which I took from [here](https://github.com/million12/docker-nginx/blob/master/container-files/config/init/vhost-default.conf)):

```
server {
    listen      80  default_server;
    listen      81  default_server http2 proxy_protocol; ## Needed when behind HAProxy with SSL termination + HTTP/2 support
    listen      443 default_server ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/dummy.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/dummy.key;

    root        /data/www;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/stub-status.conf;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-*.conf;
    include     /data/conf/nginx/conf.d/default-*.conf;
}
```

I can't find why the file is downloaded instead of display it's content.

Inside the container this is what I have at `/var/run`:

```
# ls -la /var/run/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 185 Dec 14 21:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 299 Dec 14 21:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Sep  5 10:19 blkid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Jul 29 14:05 console
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Jul 29 14:05 faillock
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  35 Jul 29 14:05 lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Jul 29 14:05 log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2 Dec 14 21:12 php-fpm.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Jul 29 14:05 sepermit
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Jul 29 14:05 setrans
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   3 Dec 14 21:12 supervisord.pid
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 113 Jul 29 14:05 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Jul 29 14:05 user
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp   0 Jul 29 14:05 utmp
```

Maybe this line:

```
 fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
```

Isn't working properly. Changing it to:

```
fastcgi_pass    php-upstream;
```

Where `php-upstream` is:

```
upstream php-upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Doesn't work either. I am stuck at this point. I have checked all of this posts before open <strike>another</strike> a new one:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950129/nginx-doesnt-serve-php-files (this was open by myself time ago)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103328/nginx-downloads-php-instead-of-running-it
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280977/nginx-php-page-downloads-instead-of-displaying
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668886/nginx-and-fastcgi-downloads-php-files-instead-of-processing-them
- [Install Nginx/PHP-FPM on Fedora 25/24, CentOS/RHEL 7.2/6.8](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

Can any give me some help on this one? Remember all this is running inside a Docker container so maybe some commands aren't available.

Comment: Please paste the contents of your www.conf file from php-fpm.  Usually it is in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`.  In particular, look for the `listen` directive in the `www.conf` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the php-fpm checklist that I use.

1. Make sure php-fpm is installed and running

   ```
   sudo systemctl status php-fpm
   ```
2. Check the `listen` directive in php-fpm configuration

   ```
   sudo cat /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf | grep -Ei '^listen'
   ```

   and make sure that the listen directive matches the upstream that you have set in your nginx configuration
3. If using unix sockets, make sure the socket is readable/writable by the php-fpm user (php-fpm user is set by the `user` and `group` directives in www.conf).  If using TCP/IP socket, check to make sure php-fpm is listening on the port with:

   ```
   sudo lsof -i :9000 # or whatever the port number you have specified
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing http2 from 'listen' section in you virtual host config and see if it works.

Had similar issue when nginx was incorrectly compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to add `?$query_string` at the end of /index.php, like below:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```